# getSharedPreferences crashes with path-based preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I was doing:

```
mPrefs = theActivity.getSharedPreferences("SomeApp/SomePrefs.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and this caused Android to crash. Not sure what exception it was throwing.

When I changed that string to `"SomeApp_SomePrefs.prefs"` things started working.

Where is it documented that a slash is verboten?

How can I find out what exception is being thrown?

Comment: "How can I find out what exception is being thrown?" - have you heard of the logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

`name` parameter of `getSharedPreferences` class is a file name. `/` is not allowed in file names.